# Angular - Object is possibly 'undefined' in Angular PatchValue Update

Tags: angular

I am implementing PatchValue for update in Angular-12.

API JSON Response:

```
"message": "Student Detail.",
"error": false,
"code": 200,
"results": {
    "student": {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "ALEX",
        "last_name": "KOY",
        "activity": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "student_id": 1,
                "activity_name": "Swimming",
               "activitytype": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "type_name": "Compulsory",
               }  
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

From the above, a student gets involved in one activity name

interface:

```
export class StudentResponse {
 results!: { student: IStudent;};
}

export interface IStudent {
  id?: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  activity?: IActivity[];
}

export interface IActivity {
  id?: number;
  type_id? number; 
  activitytype?: {id:number,type_name:string};
  activity_name: string;
}
```

service:

```
getStudentById(id: number): Observable<StudentResponse> {
  return this.http.get<StudentResponse>(this.api.baseURL + 'students/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
}
```

component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.updateStudent();
  this.loadStudentById();
}

updateStudent(){
  this.studentForm  = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    last_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    activity_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    type_id: [''],
  });
 }

 get fp(){ return this.studentForm.controls; };

loadStudentById() {
 this.studentService.getStudentById(this._id)
 .subscribe(
  (data: StudentResponse) => {
    this.student = data.results.student;
    this.studentForm.patchValue({
      first_name: this.student.first_name,
      last_name: this.student.last_name,
      activity_name: this.student.activity[0]?.activity_name,
    });
  }
 );
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div *ngIf="student != undefined">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="first_name">First Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.touched && fp.first_name.invalid">
      <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('required')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          First Name is required!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('minlength')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          First Name cannot be less than 2 characters!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('maxlength')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          First Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="last_name">Last Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.touched && fp.last_name.invalid">
      <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('required')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          Last Name is required!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('minlength')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          Last Name cannot be less than 2 characters!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('maxlength')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          Last Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="activity_name">Activity Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="activity_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
console.log(this.student)
```

gives:

```
Object
 id: 4
 alex_name: "ALEX"
 last_name: "ROY"
 activity: Array(1)
  0:
   id: 1
   type_id: 1
   activitytype: {id: 1, type_name: "Compulsory", …}
   activity_name: "Swimming"
```

This is to first retreive the data before I eventually submit to update records

I got this error in the component:

> Object is possibly 'undefined

> (property) IStudent.activity?: IActivity[] | undefined

this is highlighted:

> this.student.activity[]

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The warning is correct.

On the line that you make

```
.subscribe(
  (data: StudentResponse) => {
    this.student = data.results.student;
    this.studentForm.patchValue({
      first_name: this.student.first_name,
      last_name: this.student.last_name,
      activity_name: this.student.activity[].activity_name, <--------------
    });
  }
 );
```

`this.student.activity[]` Is not a specific activity object.

`this.student.activity[0]`, `this.student.activity[1]`, `this.student.activity[2]` could be specific activity objects which could be used.

The form model that you use though does not seem to be correct. There should be an array of activities in your form each one holding an `activity_name`

Comment: I tried each of these   this.student.activity[0], this.student.activity[1], this.student.activity[2], but the error still persists

Comment: @user11352561 try with `this.student.activity[0]?.activity_name`

Comment: The error still persists. Also I saw these: (property) IStudent.activity?: IActivity[] | undefined

Comment: update question with the code that you tried now and exactly the error that you get

Comment: @user11352561 try `this.student?.activity[0]?.activity_name` and also hit ctrl + s to save the file after editing

Comment: The same error. I editted my code with console.log(this.student) to see how the data comes. I have spent so much time on it